# Wikidata query does not give expected results

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I want to get humans whose parents who are not married (the parents are not in each others spouse property), so I write the following query

```
SELECT ?human ?father ?mother ?someone ?humanLabel ?fatherLabel ?motherLabel ?someoneLabel WHERE {
  ?human wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
  ?human wdt:P22 ?father.
  ?human wdt:P25 ?mother.
  ?father wdt:P26 ?someone.
  FILTER (?mother != ?someone)
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
 }limit 100
```

Then I discover if one person has several spouses, then the results give me lots of garbage. take Q15904745 as an example, his father(Q198042) has 2 spouse records, and his mother(Q16603522) is one of the spouse, but his info still will returns and i do not want to include this.

I would like to ask how can I change my query to get what I want? Here is the [link](https://query.wikidata.org/) to Wikidata endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If something like [this](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20distinct%20%3Fhuman%20%3Ffather%20%3Fmother%20%3Fsomeone%20%3FhumanLabel%20%3FfatherLabel%20%3FmotherLabel%20%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fhuman%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ5.%0A%20%20%3Fhuman%20wdt%3AP22%20%3Ffather.%0A%20%20%3Fhuman%20wdt%3AP25%20%3Fmother.%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28NOT%20EXISTS%20%7B%3Ffather%20wdt%3AP26%20%3Fmother%20%7D%29%20.%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28NOT%20EXISTS%20%7B%3Fmother%20wdt%3AP26%20%3Ffather%20%7D%29%20.%20%20%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20%7D%0A%20%7D%0Aorder%20by%20%3FhumanLabel%0Alimit%20100):

```
    SELECT distinct ?human ?father ?mother ?someone ?humanLabel ?fatherLabel ?motherLabel 
WHERE {
  ?human wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
  ?human wdt:P22 ?father.
  ?human wdt:P25 ?mother.
  FILTER (NOT EXISTS {?father wdt:P26 ?mother }) .
  FILTER (NOT EXISTS {?mother wdt:P26 ?father }) .  
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
 }
order by ?humanLabel
limit 100
```

Comment: hi, i think this one returns persons whose parents get married. But i want persons whose parents do not get married.

Comment: hi, when human's father or mother has more than one spouse record, this human will also appear in the final result set (when sparql matches his parent spouse record to another spouse which is not his real parent) and i do not want to include this.

Comment: @Charlotte, added distinct, please check, I don't see any duplicates

Comment: it's not about duplicate. take Q15904745 as an example, his father(Q198042) has 2 spouse records, and his mother(Q16603522) is one of the spouse, but his info still will returns.

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want.

```
    SELECT ?human ?father ?mother  ?humanLabel ?fatherLabel ?motherLabel  WHERE {
  ?human wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
  ?human wdt:P22 ?father.
  ?human wdt:P25 ?mother.
  MINUS {?mother wdt:P26 ?father.}

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
 }limit 100
```

It will exclude all people whose parents have ever married. However, I can't claim to have tested it thoroughly.

Comment: hi, when human's father or mother has more than one spouse record, this human will also appear in the final result set (when sparql matches his parent spouse record to another spouse which is not his real parent) and i do not want to include this.